# In what order should you list CSS properties for greatest speed?

Tags: performance, css, processing-efficiency, css-parsing

Let's take some CSS properties and place them randomly in our CSS file:

> outline
>   pseudo-elements
>   Color Properties
>   Background and Border Properties
>   Box Properties
>   Flexible Box Layout
>   Text Properties
>   Text Decoration Properties
>   Font Properties
>   Writing Modes
>   Table Properties
>   Lists
>   Animation

---

If you want to maximize rendering speed, in what order should you list your CSS properties?

Comment: The order doesn't matter that much for browser read speeds, if you want better performing CSS then follow the tips in YSlow (FireBug add-in) or PageSpeed...

Comment: Rather than css order you'll find [efficiently rendering css](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) is more important.

Comment: Reading that very post got me to ask this question. Upon further thought. Each browser is probably different because they have rendering agents?

Comment: Thats right, check with each:
* Edge → [EdgeHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML) (clean-up fork of Trident)
* Firefox → [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29)
* Opera → [Presto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29) (no longer uses Presto since Feb 2013, consider Opera = Chrome nowadays)
* Safari → [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)
* Chrome → [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_%28web_engine%29) (a fork of WebKit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer is: it doesn't matter.**

To elaborate on that: Say you would implement a browser<sup>1</sup> and get to the part where you parse CSS. How would you do that? Well, there is a [grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/) of CSS, so you use that to [tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) the stylesheet, build an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the stylesheet. This approach means that you would need to read everything<sup>2</sup> before you can start to actually *interpret* the stylesheet. That is, apply the selectors to your DOM (also something you parsed, but from the HTML source instead of the CSS) and then apply the rules to elements matching those selectors. Note that everything we are doing so far is only modifying state of our data structures. We store on our elements what they *should* look like.

When that is done, the [layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/) phase can begin (and with modern CSS, that is even harder thanks to [flexible box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) and [grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) layouts). It sounds simple: calculate where every element will end up on the page. It's not, but suppose that we are great programmers with a thorough understanding of the specifications that we need to adhere to, so we can do this. What do we need to know? Well, all rules that apply to all elements. It's as simple as that. We cannot calculate a layout to then learn from the parser that *"oh wait, I forgot, this element all the way at the start of the HTML source is in fact [positioned absolutely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Absolute_positioning), so you should start over with your positioning"*. So, we need to have processed everything in the stylesheet. The order in which we learned about the rules **does not matter**.

As if that is not enough, the next phase for our browser would be to draw everything, which again is nontrivial. Are you excited about building your own browser yet?

If you are really interested in how the major browsers implemented all of this, you can have a look at their engines. I am not familiar with those at all, but I know that they are... intimidating.

So, [ye be warned](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Pirates_Ye_Be_Warned_sign).

•  Chrome (Chromium) uses [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(web_engine)) ([source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master),  forked from [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)).
•  Edge uses [EdgeHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML) (forked from [Trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine))).
•  Firefox uses [Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_(software)) ([source code](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev)), but is working on a new engine called [Servo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_(layout_engine)) ([source code](https://github.com/servo/servo)).
•  Internet Explorer uses [Trident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)).
•  Opera uses [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(web_engine)) (used [Presto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_%28layout_engine%29) before Opera 15).
•  Safari uses [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) ([source code](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit)).

I included links to source code as much as I could, but some browser engines are proprietary. The source of Presto was leaked some time ago, but I won't link to that here. You may be able to find it.

*Disclaimer: I merely scratched the surface of building a browser. I haven't discussed interactivity, implementing a JavaScript engine, making HTTP requests, debugging tools, GUI design and implementation, et cetera.<sup>3</sup> Building a browser is merely used to have a story in this answer. If you are actually interested in building a browser, <s>consider these great resources</s><sup>4</sup> don't. Rather, contribute to the development of your favorite browser, if it is open source!*

**Want to read more?**
•  [This Mozilla Hacks article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/08/inside-a-super-fast-css-engine-quantum-css-aka-stylo/) has a nice explanation of how a rendering engine roughly works.
        *It also includes pretty drawings!*

____________________
  <sup>1</sup> You don't want to do that. Seriously. It's a *lot* of work. But, say you would.
  <sup>2</sup> Except maybe if you would be willing to work with the AST *while* it is built. But that is hard and error prone. It also won't gain you much in the end, as we'll see later.
  <sup>3</sup> That is discussed in a little more detail in [this Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/05/quantum-up-close-what-is-a-browser-engine/).
  <sup>4</sup> There never were any, you don't need to check the revision history of this post. It's just a joke.
     Sorry if you find it a lame one.