# Can @media be included in Scss partials below each element to speed up editing?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I just converted my css project over to scss and now that I am flipping back and forth between various partials I am wondering if it would just be easier to write my @media rules for an element right in the file below the corresponding selector, rather than at the bottom in a specific @media file?

For example the standard css method:

```
#header {
/* css style */
}
#nav{
/* css style */
}
.nav-container {
/* css style */
}
.
. 700+ lines of css...
.
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
#header {
/* new css style */
}
#nav{
/* new css style */
}
}

@media-queries screen and (max-width: 600px)*/
.nav-container {
/* new css style */
}
}
```

Versus what I would prefer to write in Scss partials:

```
_header.scss

#header {
/* css style */
}
// HEADER @MEDIA-QUERIES
@media-queries screen and (max-width: 600px)
/* new header css style */
@media-queries screen and (max-width: 400px)*/
/* new header css style */

_nav.scss

#nav {
/* css style */
}
.nav-container {
/* css style */
}
// NAV @MEDIA-QUERIES
@media-queries screen and (max-width: 600px)
/* new nav css style */
@media-queries screen and (max-width: 400px)*/
/* new nav css style */
/* new nav-container css style */
```

Is this second method an acceptable practice?
Why or why not?

A similar question was asked 5years ago but only ever answered by a robot with advice that didn't seem very decisive. [CSS media queries placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064868/css-media-queries-placement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the question you have linked says, the order does not matter so the second method is acceptable. But if you are using scss, there is even a better way because it allows you to nest your `@media` rules inside your selector. So you can even do this:

```css
#header {
  color: red;
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    color: blue;
  }
}

.nav-container {
  /* css style */

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* css style */
  }
}
```

The order does matter between individual `@media` rules. Like you should not place `@media (max-width: 600px)` after `@media (max-width: 400px)`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792163/15393728)